# In C++ I'm getting an error when using a queue and libcurl

Tags: c++, http, web-crawler, libcurl

I'm using C++ and libcurl to make a Web Spider.  I'm running into a issue where I get a error saying HTTP is not supported when I use the queue to get the URL.  Th error is: `http://google.com* Protocol "http not supported or disabled in libcurl* Unsupported protocol`.  This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <curl/curl.h>

std::string data; //will hold the url's contents

size_t writeCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up)
{ //callback must have this declaration
    //buf is a pointer to the data that curl has for us
    //size*nmemb is the size of the buffer

    for (int c = 0; c<size*nmemb; c++)
    {
        data.push_back(buf[c]);
    }
    return size*nmemb; //tell curl how many bytes we handled
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::queue<std::string> Q;
    Q.push("http://google.com");

    while (!Q.empty()) {
        std::string url = Q.front();
        std::cout << Q.front();
        CURL* curl; //our curl object

        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL); //pretty obvious
        curl = curl_easy_init();

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, &url);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &writeCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L); //tell curl to output its progress

        curl_easy_perform(curl);

        std::cout << std::endl << data << std::endl;
        std::cin.get();

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
        curl_global_cleanup();
        data.erase();
        Q.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to C++.  What direction should I look in to find out how-to fix this?

Comment: The error is most-likely unrelated to `std::queue`. Have you checked whether your version of `libcurl` supports HTTP at all?

Comment: It works if I just hardcode a URL. If I change `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, &url);` to `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://google.com");` it works

Comment: Err... You should use a `char *`, not a `std::string*`. Try `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is not `char*`. You cannot say

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, &url);
```

because this gives `std::string*` as an option and not `char*`. The correct way would be

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```

Comment: Awesome this worked! Thanks for the explanation of why it works.  I'll mark as correct in 5 mins (Stack overflow makes me wait)

Answer (score 3):

This is wrong:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, &url);
```

This is right:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
```